# Detect machine identifier (mac address) of a user.

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, identifier, mac-address

I want to detect machine identifier of an user with PHP. We know we can get the IP address. But aside from the IP address, can I get any unique identification about the computer they are using? I need the code with PHP.

Comment: You mean **MAC Address** right ? Well, sadly that cannot be obtained.

Comment: You can try using a technique like this: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: If you want to get MAC or something like that, you would use javascript or activex control. I read an article long time ago and it said you can do this with this technology.

Comment: No you can't (with JS). And ActiveX? Well.. IE-only crap. Don't be that guy who forces people to use IE.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the MAC address of a user.

Comment: Yes I understood that. I need the answer for general. Not only for MAC. If you have the solution please let me know.